# mongodb Update Specific Elements of an Array of Documents

Tags: mongodb

Information update does not work, according to the example from the documentation: [Update Specific Elements of an Array of Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter)

```
{
   "_id" : 1,
   "grades" : [
      { "grade" : 80, "mean" : 75, "std" : 6 },
      { "grade" : 85, "mean" : 90, "std" : 4 },
      { "grade" : 85, "mean" : 85, "std" : 6 }
   ]
}
{
   "_id" : 2,
   "grades" : [
      { "grade" : 90, "mean" : 75, "std" : 6 },
      { "grade" : 87, "mean" : 90, "std" : 3 },
      { "grade" : 85, "mean" : 85, "std" : 4 }
   ]
}

db.students2.update(
   { },
   { $set: { "grades.$[elem].mean" : 100 } },
   {
     multi: true,
     arrayFilters: [ { "elem.grade": { $gte: 85 } } ]
   }
)
```

Error: No array filter found for identifier 'element' in path 'grades.$[element]'

[Query && Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmzC5.png)

[Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgDoe.png)

The documentation declares support for Mongo from version 3.6. I'm using Version 3.6.

Tell me why there is an error?

Comment: You have to upgrade your robomongo version as well

Comment: Can you post the query and dataset as text in the question?